# What is the difference between KeywordCriteria and TaxonomyKeywordNameCriteria?

Tags: content-delivery

On the Content Delivery side we appear to have two very similar criterias for pulling content based on Keywords:

- KeywordCriteria
- TaxonomyKeywordNameCriteria

They both take a Category and Keyword as parameters.  The only difference I can see is that KeywordCriteria takes a Category name, whereas TaxonomyKeywordNameCriteria takes the Cateogory ID (taxonomyID).  However, this subtle difference doesn't seem to justify having completely separate classes. So I am inclined to think that there is more to it.

Would you please help me understand what the purpose of each class is and what is the difference?  In what scenarios do I use one over the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Functionally there are some differences:

- `KeywordCriteria` allows string arrays (several keywords to be queried at once). So in one query, you can retrieve all items that are tagged with any of those keywords;
- `TaxonomyKeywordNameCriteria` allows query on branches of a keyword. So in one query, you can retrieve all items that are tagged with the keyword you specified or with any child keyword of it;

Technically, some differences:

- they query different tables in the CD DB (not sure exactly which ones, but I suspect `TAXYFACETS` - `TaxonomyKeywordNameCriteria` and `ITEMS_CATEGORIES_AND_KEYWORDS` - `KeywordCriteria`;
- `TaxonomyKeywordNameCriteria` requires the taxonomy to be published. `KeywordCriteria` does not;

Comment: Key point is that for TaxonomyNameCriteria the Category must be published.

Answer (score 7):

From the API Documentation:

`TaxonomyKeywordNameCriteria`This is the criteria which can be used to retrieve all content related to any keyword with the given name.

`KeywordCriteria`This restricts the results of a query to all the content which is directly related to a specific keyword with the specified URI. This keyword could occur in multiple taxonomies/locations and is not context specific. For this use the TaxonomyFacetCriteria and BranchedTaxonomyFacetCriteria.

So I think you are right,one obvious difference is the ability to retrieve the category name. However I think that the biggest difference is the class they inherit from, they both inherit from a common `com.tridion.broker.querying.criteria.Criteria` class, but the `TaxonomyKeywordNameCriteria` inherits from `com.tridion.broker.querying.criteria.taxonomy.AbstractTaxonomyKeywordCriteria` which allows you to specify whether to allow branches or not (another slight difference).

After doing a "where used" in eclipse I couldn't find much more. I think it is an abstaction layer added to the API, so it can be extended/overwritten for future functionality.

Comment: The other difference is that apparently you can use a LIKE type query with KeywordCriteria and presumably not with the TaxonomyKeywordName class. I suspect that both are in the API for historic reasons (KeywordCriteria being present earlier than TaxonomyKeywordNameCriteria). If you look into the Broker DB table layout, you see a similar mingle of where Category / Keyword relations related to Tridion items are stored.